# Sharing a folder through NFSv4 and Samba

Tags: linux, nfs, access-control-list, nfs4

I have some trouble getting the proper access right to work for a folder shared through samba *and* nfs. Connected like this:

```
┌────────────┐    ┌──────────────┐    ┌──────────────┐
│ NFS-Server ├────┤ NFS Client   ├────┤ Samba Client │
│            │    │ Samba Server │    │              │
└────────────┘    └──────────────┘    └──────────────┘
```

The machine in the middle is a shared development machine (running Linux). The Samba clients are usually Windows. The reason this is connected like this is because of the network policy / firewall. It would be strongly discouraged to access the NFS server by Samba directly.

Additionally, as a side-effect this setup gives everyone samba access to the development machine.

The exported NFS resources should be read/writable by a specific group. I implemented this using Unix ACLs. When accessing the share via the development machine (the NFS client) directly, this already gives me trouble. It seems that the `mask` is not properly kept.

I have found a couple of resource on the web covering this topic, but I still have trouble understanding exactly why/how this is happening.

I also came across NFSv4 ACLs which are different from the ACLs you set using `setfacl`. I tried to play around with those as well, but running the command, gave me an error:

```
[11:24:32] michel@BBS-extractor coftp $ nfs4_getfacl .
Operation to request attribute not supported.
```

I thought this might be a problem related to mount options. However, the underlying FS is an `ext4` volume. Which has nothing to do with NFS... right?

Can someone explain to me what's happening here? Why is the default `mask` ignored when using NFS?

As a practical example, let me give you the ACLs of the root folder:

```
[11:30:26] michel@BBS-extractor coftp $ getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: coftp
# group: coftp
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:coftp:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:coftp:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

After creating a folder named `test` on the remote machine, I get this:

```
[11:30:26] michel@BBS-extractor coftp $ getfacl test
# file: test
# owner: michel
# group: coftp
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx                      #effective:r-x
group:coftp:rwx                 #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:coftp:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

This shows, that the group "coftp" won't have write access to this folder, although in the ACL on the root folder, it should have. The reason being the `mask`. The root folder specifies a default mask, but it seems to be ignored/changed when accessing the folder via NFS.